# Can the quick-save button be made to overwrite old save games?

Tags: far-cry-2

Far cry 2 automatically assigns a 'Quick Save' option to the key `F5`, which is great, because I find the Far Cry 2 Save menu very clunky.

However, it auto-saves to a new file, or slot, when I'd prefer it just overwrote the most recent. Normally, if I want another save for whatever reason I'll go into the save menu manually.

Is there any way to tweak Far Cry 2 to Quicksave over the top of an older save file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am not aware of any way to change the quicksave function to what you want.**

In the end, I just used the quicksave function whenever I felt it necessary and then before quitting the game, I would just delete all but the most recent save game.

Clunky, yes, but it was the only way I could play without needing to fiddle with the menu each time I wanted to save, while also avoiding the problem of hundreds of savegames littering my hard drive.

Comment: Save files are at least located in an easily accessible location: Documents/My Games/FarCry 2/Saved Games. Just go in occasionally and wipe out the old ones. Do note that FC2 will become increasingly unstable as the amount of save files increases.

Comment: @Krael - What DOESN'T cause Far Cry 2 to become increasingly unstable? :P. Thanks Steve, +1